# Bazel cc_toolchain for non-gnu TI DSP compiler

Tags: build, cross-compiling, bazel

I'm porting a TI C6000 DSP build from Makefile to Bazel.  This DSP is running on a very complex embedded system, and we are already building the same code for multiple other processors using Bazel, but those other processors use GNU flavored (e.g. `gcc`-based) compilers.

The `cc_rules` package seems to make assumptions about the flags, filename extensions etc.  I'm hoping I can avoid creating a completely custom toolchain, which would involve porting all the existing BUILD files to use different rules depending on the toolchain.

I can't seem to find any documentation on customizing those attributes, or others.  The things that I already know I need to customize:

1. The flag that is used to specify the output file: `-fr=filename` and `-fs=filename` vs `-o filename`
2. Implicit dependency generation: someone told me that `cc_rules` generates `.d` files under the hood to detect whether you have missing dependencies.  I'm not sure if this is true or not, but if so, I need to change the flag and extension used
3. The extension of the object and library files: as noted above, we build the same files for multiple CPUs, and need to customize the extension of the output for the rules.

There are probably other requirements that I'm not aware of yet as well.  It very may well be that I'm doing it all wrong and should take a different approach. We have been using Bazel since the early days (`v0.12`), and still may have holdovers from then.

We are currently on `v1.1.0`, which I ported us to from `v0.12` six months ago. I'm surprised that the master branch is already on  `v3.???`!!!

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Please remind me if I've left out anything important.

EDIT: One thing to note is that the compiler appears to be based on `clang` and `llvm`.  If there are examples of `clang`/`llvm`-based toolchains (I'm pretty sure there are) then I could get started there.

I know that the `enscriptem` example in the docs is technically a LLVM-based compiler, but that uses a script to do magic to the params, etc.  I can do that if that's the right thing to do, but I want to make sure I'm headed down the right path.

Comment: You will need a custom toolchain, but it's not as arcane as it used to be and it's largely a one time effort. Doing so is actually provides common abstraction (and if needed you can also throw in few extra features), so that you have one  tree of `BUILD` files that works independent of toolchain used. I'd start [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html) and [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) perhaps. Looking at the templates in bazel src tree or [rules_cc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc) helps too.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I'll take a look

Comment: Oh, sorry, I don't think I was clear.  I'm actually already doing that. The problem I'm having (and it might very well be because of my ignorance) is that the generic `cc_compiler` toolchain support seems to assume `gcc` semantics for the tools.  Like, for example, `-o outputfile` means write the compile intermediary file to `outputfile`.  I don't see a way to customize that behavior.

Comment: Ok, I found this: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8b9f74649512ee17ac52815468bf3d7e5e71c9fa/tools/cpp/unix_cc_toolchain_config.bzl

It seems to have many of the default settings in it, which I can override by overriding the appropriate "features".  For example, with dependency generation, I can override the "dependency_file_feature"

Comment: Yep, nowadays the behavior and flags can be reasonably well controlled with Starlark and tookchain definition.

Comment: I'm still having trouble finding the right way to override the `-o %{output_execpath}` default behavior.  Is there a list of all the default features I can find somewhere?

Comment: for the `-o` option, I ported this to Starlark: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/71dcb1039e3fe803c84542c75554341559b36306/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppActionConfigs.java#L1532

It would be great if there was a document or other list that shows all of the default features in the CC library to make porting new compilers easier.  It seems like there must be, and I just never found it.

Comment: Ok, so I learned that adding an empty feature with the name `no_legacy_features` will remove all default options and allow me to build a  CC toolchain from the bottom up.  That's probably the best way to do things at this point. https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#legacy-features-patching-logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to all of your questions, but this also goes beyond what could be formatted and posted as comment. To your most recent inquiry. This snippet would redefine option used for output file (instead of `-o OUTPUT` to `-fr=OUTPUT`):

```
    compiler_output_flags_feature = feature(
        name = "compiler_output_flags",
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = [
                    ACTION_NAMES.assemble,
                    ACTION_NAMES.c_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_header_parsing,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_codegen,
                ],
                flag_groups = [
                    flag_group(
                        flags = ["-fr=%{output_file}"],
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )
```

As for available and used actions, you can check [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/cc/action_names.bzl) out. For features, as you've already discovered: disabling legacy features and see what you need is one option. There is also this [list](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#legacy-features-patching-logic) in the docs that you've stumbled upon. Beyond that (incl. what variables are available at which point), it's a bit of "use the source, Luke" at least that's where I usually for better or worse ended heading for details. For action a good point would be [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CppActionConfigs.java).

But I also find checking out other pre-packaged toolchain configs (esp. [MSVC](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/blob/master/cc/private/toolchain/windows_cc_toolchain_config.bzl) for being... different) insightful.

Comment: Hi there Ondrej, thanks for your excellent response. I figured this out right before you posted it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding your own custom rule that provides `CcToolchainConfigInfo`, would solve the problem you are having.

```
def _impl(ctx):
    tool_paths = [
        tool_path(name = "gcc", path = "/<abs>/<path>/clang"),
        tool_path(name = "ld", path = "/<abs>/<path>/ld"),
        tool_path(name = "ar", path = "/<abs>/<path>/ar"),
        tool_path(name = "cop", path = "/bin/false"),
        tool_path(name = "gcov", path = "/bin/false"),
        tool_path(name = "nm", path = "/bin/false"),
        tool_path(name = "objdump", path = "/bin/false"),
        tool_path(name = "strip", path = "/bin/false"),
    ]

    toolchain_compiler_flags = feature(
        name = "compiler_flags",
        enabled = True,
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = [
                    ACTION_NAMES.assemble,
                    ACTION_NAMES.preprocess_assemble,
                    ACTION_NAMES.linkstamp_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.c_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_header_parsing,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_compile,
                    ACTION_NAMES.cpp_module_codegen,
                    ACTION_NAMES.lto_backend,
                    ACTION_NAMES.clif_match,
                ],
                flag_groups = [
                    flag_group(flags = ["<compiler-flags>"]),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )

    toolchain_linker_flags = feature(
        name = "linker_flags",
        enabled = True,
        flag_sets = [
            flag_set(
                actions = [
                    ACTION_NAMES.linkstamp_compile,
                ],
                flag_groups = [
                    flag_group(flags = ["<linker-flags>"]),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    )

    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        toolchain_identifier = ctx.attr.toolchain_identifier,
        host_system_name = ctx.attr.host_system_name,
        target_system_name = "<your-system-name>",
        target_cpu = "<your-cpu>",
        target_libc = "<your-libc>",
        compiler = "<your-compiler>,
        abi_version = "<your-eabiu>",
        abi_libc_version = <your-version>,
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
        features = [
            toolchain_compiler_flags,
            toolchain_linker_flags,
            <more-custom-features>,
        ],
    )

cc_arm_none_eabi_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "toolchain_identifier": attr.string(default = ""),
        "host_system_name": attr.string(default = ""),
    },
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

I have posted an [example about using GCC embedded toolchains with Bazel](https://github.com/d-asnaghi/bazel-arm-none-eabi) on Github that you could use as a template. The example works with the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler, but in principle, it would work just as well with `clang`.

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for the response.  The problem I'm having is that there are several default features that add flags assuming a `gcc`-link compiler.  I've mostly resolved this issue by overriding the default features, but I've had to pour through the source to figure out what features add which flags in order to figure out what features to override.  I'm also having trouble because part of our build system requires using alternative file extensions for generated files, which seem to be hard coded into the CC Toolchain infrastructure